# Subtitle with the \maketitle page?

Tags: titles

Does there exist some command for subtitles in the `\maketitle` thing?

Comment: The `titlepage` environment can be used to create a title page with everything you need. The standard classes don't even try to provide "everything" one could need. You can look at the `titling` package for getting aid in designing a title.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In the standard classes: no. In the [`KOMA-Script`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) classes: yes.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\title{(Title)}
\subtitle{(Subtitle)}
\author{(Author)}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How about `subsubsub...title`?

Comment: @hhh AFAIK, no class/package offers this.

Answer (score 61):

With the `titling` package one can define a `\subtitle` command as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.5em}%
}

\begin{document}

\title{(Title)}
\subtitle{(Subtitle)}

\author{(Author)}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The trick is that `titling` redefines `\maketitle` so that it executes, among other things

```
<pretitle tokens> <title tokens> <posttitle tokens>
```

and what goes in `<posttitle tokens>` is set by

```
\posttitle{tokens}
```

The default, as made clear in the documentation, is

```
  \posttitle{\par\end{center}\vskip0.5em}
```

so what's needed is to insert something in between.

[image]

Comment: ...how about `subsubsub...title`?

Comment: @hhh What do you mean?

Comment: Like is it possible to have `\subsubtitle{...}`? At least with the `\title{...}` linebreaks do not work in title -element `\title{oneLine\n newLine}`.

Comment: Use ``\\`` to force a line break.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for the helpful solution here. Unfortunately I'm running into an error when trying to include an abstract and multiple authors. I posted a separate question about the issue here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285711/subtitle-abstract-and-multiple-authors-using-titling-package

Comment: @EthanAlvaree I believe there's no hope in making `titling` to cooperate with `amsart`.

Comment: I've attempted something similar involving invoking `\posttitle` with the code to close off `\pretitle` first, then, inside `\subtitle`, `\let`ting `\oldposttitle` to it before redefining `\posttitle` to use `\oldposttitle`, but I wasn't able to get it to work the same way…

Comment: @RandomDSdevel Probably a fresh question with the attempt and the aim is better.

Comment: @egreg:  Eh, I got something else to work, so it's not really that important any more; I just wanted to add what I said as a note.

Comment: See my separate answer for an example that works with `amsart`.

Comment: Thanks this approach works better than the others, since it's more compatible with other sytles.

Answer (score 8):

Remember also that you can easily make subtitle with a little hack:

```
\title{This is the main title of my work.\\ \small And this is the subtitle}
```

In most cases, it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

I was inspired by Enrico's suggestion, but didn't want to use the `titling` package because it's not included in BasicTeX and some other minimal TeX distributions, so I added a subtitle using `etoolbox` instead. This also won't clash with KOMA-Script or other classes that add their own version of `\subtitle`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\providecommand{\subtitle}[1]{% add subtitle to \maketitle
  \apptocmd{\@title}{\par {\large #1 \par}}{}{}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{(Title)}
\subtitle{(Subtitle)}
\author{(Author)}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't place the `\usepackage{etoolbox}` inside the definition of `\subtitle`.

Comment: Is there a reason for that? The idea was to load `etoolbox` only if the command were used.

Comment: You call `\title` inside the preamble (before `\begin{document}`). However, without your patch, you *can* call `\title` after `\begin{document}`. One issue, `\usepackage` can only be used inside the preamble which forces `\title` to be used in the preamble. It's just not common practice.