# How can I effect line breaks within the title without hardcoding \\'s in \title?

Tags: hyperref, line-breaking, titles

Although I do need line breaks within my title for my document's title page (I'm using the `book` class), I'd like to avoid hardcoding line breaks in the argument passed to the `\title` command, for three reasons:

1. I always endeavour to separate form and content, for maintainability reasons.
2. The title may need to be inserted elsewhere in the document, in places where line breaks within it are not warranted.
3. I pass my title to`\hypersetup{pdftitle=...}`; `hyperref` returns a warning,

> Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEnconding):(hyper ref) removing `\\'

if the title contains some `\\`, and I want to limit the number of compilation warnings to the bare minimum.

How can I effect line breaks at specific places within the title, upon inserting the latter somewhere in my document, *without* hardcoding `\\`'s in the `\title{...}` command? What's the best practice?

```
\documentclass{book}

\author{Me, me, me}
%\title{Me, myself, and I}      % compiles without mishap; strictly content
\title{Me,\\ myself, \\ and I}  % compilation warnings occur; form and content are mixed

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\hypersetup{
    pdftitle = \@title,
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \kant
\end{document}
```

Comment: @AndrewSwann I didn't think the question warranted an MWE, but sure; it's on the way.

Comment: @Jubobs, I think Andrew Swann may have had the same though as me, I'd like to figure out why you need a forced line break in the title, rather than a [subtitle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50182/subtitle-with-the-maketitle-page)

Comment: Well for one thing, the title macro depends on the documentclass, and may or may not take an optional argument that could be used.  Then there is `\textorpdfstring` for hyperref...

Comment: @ChrisH I can sympathisze with the general thought.  Title layout on the page and its line breaks is quite critical with regard to emphasing/deemphasing certain words etc.

Comment: @AndrewSwann You're right: using `\texorpdfstring` would obviate the warning. However, what about my 2nd point? What if I need to format my title in a different way, somewhere else than on the title page?

Comment: @AndrewSwann, fair enough, I've tended to find that (on the rare occasions when I have the final choice) a subtitle does the job.  For journal articles the choice of line breaking is likely to be taken away anyway, along with being able to add a subtitle.

Comment: You could use a custom command `\titlecr` that is initially `\\`, but is `\let` to `\relax` just after `\maketitle` (assuming you have saved `\@title`), or redefined to something more appropriate in other applications.

Comment: if you always want certain phrases "tied together", use the `~` (tilde = tie) instead of a space between them.  sometimes this works to encourage a line break, but sometimes you end up with an overfull box and have to break the line explicitly.  depends on how the `\title` argument is processed; the stretch has to be defined with sufficient flexibility, which depends on the document class.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I like this idea, and it seems to do the trick in my case. Would you care to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you always want certain phrases "tied together", use the `~` (tilde = tie)
instead of a space between them. sometimes this works to encourage a line break,
but sometimes you end up with an overfull box and still have to break the line explicitly.

(this is the same approach recommended in the texbook for keeping things like "`Dr.~No`"
and "`Figure~1`" from breaking apart at the end of a line.)

the actual result depends on how the `\title` argument is processed;
the stretch has to be defined with sufficient flexibility, which depends on
the document class.

Comment: This tilde trick let me line-break a section title properly, in a place where \\ would accidentally introduce a page break at the line break!

Answer (score 9):

The easiest way is using option `pdfusetitle` and without spaces around `\\` in `\title`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle]{hyperref}

\author{Me, me, me}
\title{Me,\\myself,\\and I}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \kant
\end{document}
```

Result of `pdfinfo`:

```
Title:          Me, myself, and I
Author:         Me, me, me
```

Otherwise, there is `\texorpdfstring`:

```
\title{My,\texorpdfstring{\\}{ }myself,\texorpdfstring{\\}{ }and I}
```

Or `\pdfstringdefDisableCommands` can be used, e.g.:

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\\#1{ #1}}
```

That is the definition that is used for the title with option `pdfusetitle`, it supports the following forms:

```
\title{Me,\\myself,\\and I}
\title{Me,\\ myself,\\ and I}
```

If you prefer more spaces:

```
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\\\@firstofone}
\title{Me, \\ myself, \\ and I}
```

The trick with the argument is, that TeX does not accept a space as undelimited argument. Thus the space after `\\` is gobbled.

The spaces are one of the reasons, that `\\` is not provided by `hyperref` and a warning is given. The usual tricks (`\unskip`, `\ignorespaces`, ...) are not working inside the generation of PDF strings.

Comment: Such a great answer! Thanks. I guess I can also use `\texorpdfstring` to include nonbreaking spaces in the title as recommended by Barbara.

Comment: @Jubobs: `~` is supported by `hyperref`, no need for `\texorpdfstring`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek As a substitute for `\ignorespaces` inside the generation of PDF strings, you could use `\romannumeral-^^ \q`.  Of couse, that leaves a preceeding space: this could be a problem.  Alternatively, one could implement `\unskip` by adding a step after the full expansion and after stripping braces which would strip all occurrences of `<space>\unskip`.