# Subtitle, abstract and multiple authors using Titling package

Tags: titles, amsart, titling

Following the excellent advice in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50182/subtitle-with-the-maketitle-page), I learned how to get a subtitle below the main title, using the `titling` package. Unfortunately, the trick runs into an error when you try including an abstract. Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsxtra}

\usepackage{titling}
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
\posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
\begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
\vskip0.5em}%
}

\begin{document}

\title{Title goes here}
\subtitle{Subtitle goes here}

\author{Author 1}
\address{Address 1}
\email{Email 1}

\author{Author 2}
\address{Address 2}
\email{Email 2}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Begin section 1...

\end{document}
```

Although the code compiles, it reports the warning `No \author given` and the abstract fails to appear in the PDF.

I would like to have the title, subtitle, abstract, and introduction to all appear on the 1st page. (I don't want a separate "title page", as the formatting needs to be compact for a limited-space journal article.) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you checked with the journal editors if those kinds of changes are ok?

Comment: @Johannes_B What changes do you mean? No, I haven't decided what journal to submit to yet. (But I know that space will be an issue in any journal, so that's why I don't want a separate title page.)

Comment: Many journals have a very specific layout that you have to follow. Many provide templates. As of now, i would simply write, write, write, and when you are closer to submission, take care of needed formatting.

Comment: That makes sense - thanks. Nonetheless, I'm still wondering why this code's giving me an error, and why it's not allowing me to have both a subtitle and an abstract...

Comment: Package `titling` enhances the standard clases, but has no awareness of ams-classes. `ams` allows you to issue `\author` multiple times, whereas you can't with the standard classes. In other words, package `titling` is not really suited for ams-classes (or KOMA).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `titling` package is definitely incompatible with `amsart`.

You can easily implement a `\subtitle` command:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}

\makeatletter
\def\@settitle{\begin{center}%
  \baselineskip14\p@\relax
  \bfseries
  \uppercasenonmath\@title
  \@title
  \ifx\@subtitle\@empty\else
     \\[1ex]\uppercasenonmath\@subtitle
     \footnotesize\mdseries\@subtitle
  \fi
  \end{center}%
}
\def\subtitle#1{\gdef\@subtitle{#1}}
\def\@subtitle{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\title{Title goes here}
\subtitle{Subtitle goes here}

\author{Author 1}
\address{Address 1}
\email{Email 1}

\author{Author 2}
\address{Address 2}
\email{Email 2}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Begin section 1...

\end{document}
```

However, you get essentially the same effect by doing

```
\title{%
  Title goes here\\[1ex]
  \footnotesize\mdseries
  Subtitle goes here%
}
\shorttitle{Title goes here}
```

without tampering with the class.

[image]

Comment: What excellent solutions. Thank you very much!