# Lyx: Add subtitle in stdtitle.inc

Tags: lyx, environments, lyx-layouts, modules

I would like to create a Subtitle environment that will be available in the Environments dropdown while using memoir. I've tried editing stdtitle.inc, memoir.layout, and creating a subtitle.module

This is what I am trying to define... same as "title" but one size down.

```
Style Subtitle
    Margin                Static
    LatexType             Command
    Category              FrontMatter
    InTitle               1
    LatexName             subtitle
    ParSkip               0.4
    ItemSep               0
    TopSep                0
    BottomSep             1
    ParSep                1
    Align                 Center
    LabelType             No_Label
    Font
      Size                Larger
    EndFont
End
```

Editing stdtitle.inc or memoir.layout, I do see "subtitle" in my drop menu, but on export I get the error below:

```
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed.
```

In the custom module, I get an error saying the module "subtitle" requires packages, and is missing the prerequisite "subtitle"

How do I define subtitle so 1) I can access it in the dropdown, 2) it's understood by Lyx, and 3) exports correctly?

Comment: What is the full LaTeX code that you want to produce in the end?

Comment: Hi, Scott. I'm going for the following:

`\begin{document}
\title{
Title of Novel }
\subtitle
  (Subtitle of Novel}
\author{author of book}

\end{document}`

Comment: If you post a complete minimal example .lyx file (see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample), the .tex file that that .lyx file produces, and the complete .tex file that you would *like* to produce, I can take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `memoir` doesn't provide a `\subtitle` macro by default, so when you use that layout on LyX, which ends up using the LaTeX code `\subtitle{...}`, you get an error.

To get your code to work, you can use the code from egreg's answer to [Subtitle with the \maketitle page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50182/subtitle-with-the-maketitle-page/50186#50186). While that is written for the `article` class with the `titling` package, `memoir` includes code equivalent to `titling`, so the same code seemed to work fine also with `memoir`.

Hence, use the layout you have created already, and then add

```
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.5em}%
}
```

to the preamble, either in Document -> Settings -> LaTeX preamble or in the `.module` file itself. (I don't remember how to add stuff to the preamble in a module though.)

Complete `.lyx` file:

[image]

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass memoir
\begin_preamble
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{%
  \posttitle{%
    \par\end{center}
    \begin{center}\large#1\end{center}
    \vskip0.5em}%
}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\begin_local_layout
Style Subtitle
    Margin                Static
    LatexType             Command
    Category              FrontMatter
    InTitle               1
    LatexName             subtitle
    ParSkip               0.4
    ItemSep               0
    TopSep                0
    BottomSep             1
    ParSep                1
    Align                 Center
    LabelType             No_Label
    Font
      Size                Larger
    EndFont
End
\end_local_layout
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command default
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
This
\end_layout

\begin_layout Subtitle
That
\end_layout

\begin_layout Author
Foo
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```