# Subtitle in book class

Tags: titles

I am using a specific book template (and .cls file). I want to put a subtitle. When I try to do that, an error is shown at \maketitle, saying "Use of \@icentercr doesn't match its definition.  \def " How can I fix this ? Do I have to go to the .cls file and fix it there itself.

```
\begin{document}
\title{
 Main Title \\ 
      Subtitle
 }
```

Apologies for not including a mwe, the template I'm working on, I cannot do that.

Comment: If you're open to other classes, you could use `scrbook` ([see this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50184/134574)) or other class. If `book` is required, then you can use the `titling` package ([see this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50186/134574)). Otherwise you could resort to redefining `\maketitle`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, thank you. Neither of the links helps. I can't use the former, since it needs change of the class. The latter changes original positioning of the title.

Comment: What do you mean with "changes the original positioning of the title"? Did you try a) redefining `\maketitle`? b) using t titling package?  Otherwise, we can just guess because it's clearly a problem with your "specific book template", so probably yes, you'll have to change the `.cls` file.

Comment: @Joseph, can you elaborate redefining the \maketitle.

Comment: As in `\renewcommand{\maketitle}{....}` -- find the `\maketitle` command in your class, and change it (that's more or less what the `titling` package does).

Answer (score 4):

If you *must* use `book` and *cannot* use `titling`, then you can redefine `\maketitle`.

I copied the definition from `book.cls` and added two lines:

```
    \vskip 1.5em% Added this
    {\Large \@subtitle \par}% and this
```

right below the title. I also added a wrapper command for adding the subtitle:

```
\def\subtitle#1{\gdef\@subtitle{#1}}
```

Without a MWE, this is the best one can do:

> [image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\makeatletter
\def\subtitle#1{\gdef\@subtitle{#1}}
\def\maketitle{\begin{titlepage}%
  \let\footnotesize\small
  \let\footnoterule\relax
  \let \footnote \thanks
  \null\vfil
  \vskip 60\p@
  \begin{center}%
    {\LARGE \@title \par}%
    \vskip 1.5em% Added this
    {\Large \@subtitle \par}% and this
    \vskip 3em%
    {\large
     \lineskip .75em%
      \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
        \@author
      \end{tabular}\par}%
      \vskip 1.5em%
    {\large \@date \par}%       % Set date in \large size.
  \end{center}\par
  \@thanks
  \vfil\null
  \end{titlepage}%
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}%
  \global\let\thanks\relax
  \global\let\maketitle\relax
  \global\let\@thanks\@empty
  \global\let\@author\@empty
  \global\let\@date\@empty
  \global\let\@title\@empty
  \global\let\title\relax
  \global\let\author\relax
  \global\let\date\relax
  \global\let\and\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Main Title}

\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author{Me}

\date{\today}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Or, a less messy version with `etoolbox`'s `\patchcmd`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\subtitle#1{\gdef\@subtitle{#1}}
\patchcmd\maketitle
  {{\LARGE \@title \par}}
  {{\LARGE \@title \par}%
   \vskip 1.5em
   {\Large \@subtitle \par}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Main Title}

\subtitle{Subtitle}

\author{Me}

\date{\today}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```