# How do I type a superscript in a subtitle?

Tags: titles, superscripts, texlive-2019

Here is a minimal version of what I am trying to compile:

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\title{La vie au XXI\textsuperscript{e} si\`ecle}

\subtitle{La vie au XXI\textsuperscript{e} si\`ecle}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The command I type is `pdflatex mydocument`.

The weird thing is that the title works exactly as expected, but the subtitle does not : `\textsuperscript` triggers the dreaded error message `! Undefined control sequence`. Unfortunately, I do need a superscript in the subtitle. How to achieve this?

I am using pdflatex, version: TeX Live 2019/Debian.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It's the `\subtitle` directive, not the `\superscript` directive inside the argument of `\subtitle`, that causing the error message. (To verify this assertion, simply replace `\subtitle{La vie au XXI\textsuperscript{e} si\`ecle}` with `\subtitle{La vie au XXIe si\`ecle}` and recompile.) The basic `book` document class does not define a macro called `\subtitle`. Do you maybe need to load a package in order to define `\subtitle`?

Comment: Are you certain the `undefined control sequence` is due to `\textsuperscript`? As far as I remember, ther is no `\subtitle` in a regular `book` class, so I would suspect something like `\subtitle{text}` to result in the same error message.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I had no idea that a book was not supposed to have a subtitle according to the LaTeX packages… Weird, some books do have a subtitle. I’ll just do it some other way, then.

Comment: The issue is *not* whether some books have subtitles. The issue is how to enter the subtitle information when using the `book` document class.

Comment: [Subtitle with the \maketitle page?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50182/134144) contains some information on how you can add a subtitle to your book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As some of the comments have already pointed out, the basic `book` document class does not offer a macro called `\subtitle`.

A general observation: When working with the `book` document class, the basic LaTeX `\title`, `\author`, and `\date` commands may not be sufficiently rich/flexible for you, i.e., they may not let you generate an elaborate title page. If that's the case for your document, do look into using various LaTeX packages that provide lots of extra flexibility.

If you don't want to go that route and simply wish to insert the subtitle string in a font that's slightly smaller than that of the main title string, you may do so by employing the code, shown below, that generates the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass[french]{book}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{cfr-lm} % or: "\usepackage{lmodern}"
\else
   \usepackage{fontspec}
   \setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}[Numbers=OldStyle]
\fi

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

% Default relative font size for argument of \title: "\LARGE"
\title{La vie au XXI\textsuperscript{e} siècle\\[1\baselineskip]
       \Large % or "\large" % switch to a smaller relative font size
       La vie au XXI\textsuperscript{e} siècle} % subtitle
\author{Moi}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\clearpage
% remainder of document

\end{document}
```