# How to Make a One-Time Adjustment to the Textwidth

Tags: pdftex, textwidth, adjustwidth

I would like to be able to make a one-time adjustment to the textwidth in order to have a title (or  subtitle) appear entirely on one line.

Consider the MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath,verbatim}
\oddsidemargin -8pt \evensidemargin -15pt \topmargin -25pt
\headheight -5pt \headsep 0pt \textheight 9.5in \textwidth 5.25in
\parskip 10pt

\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{LARGE}
\noindent{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\textsl{Title, Whose Length is Fine}}}}

\vspace{5pt}

\noindent{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\textsl{Subtitle Whose Length is a Little Too Long}}}}
\end{LARGE}
\large
\vspace*{15pt}

\lipsum[13]
\end{document}
```

with the output

[image]

QUESTION: How would I be able to force the statement "Subtitle Whose Length is a Little Too Long" to appear all on the same line---while not affecting the textwidth of 5.25in for the rest of the document?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd probably prefer to adjust the fontsize of the subtitle or reword it. But if you must do this, you could use `\rlap{...}`, which sets text in a zero width box and allows it to overlap to the right.

Comment: Perhaps you would also find the `geometry` package useful for setting page margins. And the `titling` package for customising a document title pae (e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50186/87678)

Comment: For such ad hoc formatting, just enclosing the title in a `\mbox` will work.  However, titles should usually be set via the markup for the given class.

Comment: @Andrew Swann Thank you. I was not aware of `\mbox`. It works very nicely. Perhaps you will consider posting this as an answer.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How can I change the margins for only part of the text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/588/5764)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The brute force way to do this is just to place the subtitle in an `\mbox`.  You will then get overfull box warnings, which is probably a good thing, but may be annoying.  The command `\mbox` is based on `\makebox` which will create boxes of given width, so to suppress warnings you can put the subtitle in `\makebox[0pt][l]{...}` a box of zero width with the content left aligned:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\oddsidemargin -8pt \evensidemargin -15pt \topmargin -25pt
\headheight -5pt \headsep 0pt \textheight 9.5in \textwidth 5.25in
\parskip 10pt

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{flushleft}
  \LARGE\color{red}\bfseries\slshape
  Title, Whose Length is Fine\\[1ex]
  \makebox[0pt][l]{Subtitle Whose Length is a Little Too Long}
\end{flushleft}

\large
\medskip

\lipsum[13]

\end{document}
```

I have also tried to simplify the other parts of the mark-up, putting all the title material in a `flushleft`, so avoiding the `\noindent` commands, and placing the font selection and color initially.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your earlier comment.

Comment: Does the ‘m’ in mbox stand for ‘make’?

Comment: @SingleMalt I believe so.  It is `\makebox` without checking of optional arguments.

Answer (score 3):

`\parbox` and `\mbox` are a bit of overkill for this case and can be challenging to generalize to other contexts.

I would instead, adjust the right margin:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\myhead}{ m }
   {%
     {\rightskip=0pt plus 1fil minus 1in % ❶
      \LARGE
      \noindent
      \textcolor{red}{\textbf{\textsl{#1}}}%
      \par
     }%
     \vspace{5pt}%
   }
```

at ❶ we set `\rightskip` to allow it to shrink by `1in` (this is an arbitrarily chosen amount and you will want to pick something that meets your needs whether you want just a little overhang or you want to be able fill in the whole margin parspace or something else entirely).

Note also, most importantly, that I've wrapped everything up in a new command so that your document isn't filled with arbitrary formatting commands so that this will be easily modifiable on a global business.

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of the large right margin by increasing the width of the marginpar area (`\marginparwidth`). Then insert the long subtitle into a `\parbox` that extends to this area.

Using a `\mbox` may seem simpler, but it won't break the line with even longer text and it will overflow the page.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath,verbatim}
\oddsidemargin -8pt \evensidemargin -15pt \topmargin -25pt
\headheight -5pt \headsep 0pt \textheight 9.5in \textwidth 5.25in
\parskip 10pt

\setlength{\marginparwidth}{120pt} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{showframe} % only to show the margins

\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{LARGE}
\noindent{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\textsl{Title, Whose Length is Fine}}}}

\vspace{5pt}

% use the margin for this long subtitle <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


\noindent\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep\relax}{\textcolor{red}{\bfseries\textsl{Subtitle Whose Length is a Little Too Long and Longer }}} 

\noindent\mbox{\textcolor{red}{\bfseries\textsl{Subtitle Whose Length is a Little Too Long and Longer}}}

\end{LARGE}
\large
\vspace*{15pt}

\lipsum[13]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about `\marginparsep`?

Comment: @Sigur Added. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The `adjustwidth` environment in the `changepage` package is designed for this.

```
% longtitleprob.tex  SE 620119
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{changepage}  %% PW added

\usepackage{amsthm,latexsym,amssymb,amsmath,verbatim}
\oddsidemargin -8pt \evensidemargin -15pt \topmargin -25pt
\headheight -5pt \headsep 0pt \textheight 9.5in \textwidth 5.25in
\parskip 10pt

\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{LARGE}
\noindent{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\textsl{Title, Whose Length is Fine}}}}

\vspace{5pt}

\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-2cm}  %% PW added
\noindent{\textcolor{red}{\textbf{\textsl{Subtitle Whose Length is a Little Too Long}}}}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{LARGE}
\large
\vspace*{15pt}

\lipsum[13]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `adjustwidth` environment takes two length arguments. `\begin{adjustwidth}{<left>}{<right>}` A positive `<left>` length will increase the left margin, thus decreasing the textwidth, while a negative length decreases the left margin, thus increasing the textwidth. Similarly for the `<right>` argument and margin. An empty argument means no adjustment. There is a starred version `adjustwidth*` which causes the values of the margins to switch between even and odd pages.